# Bundle Install not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a rails project and keep getting this error, when I try to run paperclips migration generator. It tells me to bundle install as a gems source could not be found but then when I run bundle install, everything goes fine except I get the same error message to run bundle update every time.

I had the same problem a few hours back however this time it could not find the sources for the json gem -v 1.8.1.

To solve this I ran `gem install json -v 1.8.1` and after that it all went ok. Now the problem has come back for a different gem and running gem install for the gem appears to have no effect this time.

The error I keep getting:

`Could not find climate_control-0.0.3 in any of the sources
Run bundle install to install missing gems.`

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Authentication gems
gem 'sorcery'
gem 'bcrypt'

# Photo Upload
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.1'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'rabl'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
group :development do
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'pry'
end


# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

When I run bundle install it also shows that it's using the right climate control but no luck with the error.

`Using climate_control 0.0.3`

Also it may be worth noting that I recently downloaded rvm and upgraded to ruby -v 2.1.1, don't know whether that has anything to do with it but worth letting you know.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try removing your `Gemfile.lock`, then run `bundle install` and see if everything is sorted for you.

Comment: fully delete the gemfile.lock? like rm -rf?

Comment: No need for `-rf` parameters. Just do `rm Gemfile.lock`, `bundle install`.

Comment: @kiddorails removing and retrying had no effect, still getting run bundle install climate-control no source etc.

Comment: Please show your Gemfile.  You have Paperclip in there right?  There's no need to have climate_control in your Gemfile as cocaine is a dependency of Paperclip and climate_control is a dependency of cocaine.  You should be able see these dependencies in your Gemfile.lock

Comment: Use `bundle exec` to run which ever command is producing the error. IE, `bundle exec rails s`.

Comment: @GraemeMcLean Ive updated the question with more info which hopefully will help.

Comment: @meagar it seems to me bundle exec would be a hackaround and with it happening more than once I don't want it haunting me later. Thanks for   your tips though.

Comment: `bundle exec` may seem hackish, but it’s a workaround necessary in many Ruby development environments. You can avoid it by using some combinations of Ruby and gem managers, but that’s outside the scope of this question.

Comment: @BuckDoyle Tried bundle exec and it has no effect still get the could not find sources error above?

Comment: `bundle exec` is not a "hackaround", it's how bundler is supposed to work.

Comment: me too facing same issue please help me out how you had solve it as I had removed my gem.lock file and done bundle install too but still getting error of `Could not find climate_control-0.0.3 in any of the sources`

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is removing Spring from the gemfile (for some reason it conflicts with paperclip)

I filed an issue on paperclip repo here:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/2226

I have no idea why this is happening, but users uploading files is more important than developers comfort so bye bye spring.

If I find out the exact reason why this is happening, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any ruby manager?

There might be a chance you have more than one rubies.

Also try to update your rubygems with gem update --system.

Comment: I am using rvm and I have one ruby, but your solution "gem update --system" work for me. 
Thanks